# Book Supplement to Griffth and Harris Principle in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

There is a Chapter 0 (Foundation Level) in Principle in Algebraic Geometry. What are those good book supplement to this chapter ?

Comment: Related  : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48997/griffiths-and-harris-reference

Comment: That thread has only reference about Poincare Duality, but Chapter 0 has more than these.

Comment: Sure but it is already a good start, and anyway this chapter 0 covers so much that you probably need several references.

Comment: Yes that's a problem, I don't really know which part of chapter 0 requires which book .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Huybrechts' *Complex Geometry: An Introduction* is a good book to supplement chapters $0$ and $1$ of Griffiths and Harris. It covers pretty much the same material, but often covered in more detail. In particular, section $1.2$ has a nice discussion of the multilinear algebra that you need.

Comment: It mentions in preface that we need holomorphic function in one variable , differential manifolds and sheaf theory and cohomology. I only have knowledge for holomorphic function , but not the other two. Any suggestion about books to read about differential manifold and sheaf theory as a supplement to this book ?